# Can't import third party python packages into Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, networkx

I'm getting a little desperate here. I'm trying to import the python `networkx` package and I'm using Sublime Text 2. I believe I installed it correctly using `easy_install networkx` and it downloaded online and installed. I have these two simple lines of code in a script in Sublime:

```
import networkx 
print "imported"
```

And the program returns with no error that it can't find the module, but without printing anything so I know something is off. When I try to import it within the terminal (using Cygwin) using `>> import networkx` it terminates early as well. I checked, and both my terminal and Sublime are running the same version of Python (2.7.5). I tried adding PYTHONPATH to my variables in Python.sublime-build to point to where my python packages are. Here's what it currently looks like

```
{
"env": ["PYTHONPATH":"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages",
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

I may be setting PYTHONPATH wrong but I'm not sure.

But the biggest problem is, why is the import statement terminating early???

Any help would be great, using networkx would make my life so much easier than coding all these graph algorithms myself.

Comment: So, the sublime text import *is* working and the terminal import *is not* working correct?

Comment: for which ever one is working, I would find the path of networkx. `import networkx` then `print networkx.__path__`

Comment: No, the sublime text import is not working and the terminal import is working. Sorry, I know it's confusing! I type `import networkx` into the cygwin terminal, but then the shell returns and the `>>` goes away so I can't type in `print networkx.__file__`

Comment: I mean `networkx.__path__`

Comment: on the command line `python -c 'import networkx;print networkx.__path__`